# Move Virtual Environment in Windows

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am teaching myself Python 3.6 on Windows machine.

So far I can install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper via

`pip install virtualenv
pip install virtualenvwrapper
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win`

Unable to move virtual environment to subdirectory in C:; it's in my user directory instead

Tried following, no luck

`set VIRTENV=C:\Cookbook`

doesn't give errors but any virtual environment I create goes to user directory instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for `virtualenvwrapper-win`, by default it set the location to `%USERPROFILE%\Envs` which is the user folder. That is the user folder. To change this add an environment variable `WORKON_HOME` to specify the path to store the environments. See the documentation - [documentation](https://github.com/davidmarble/virtualenvwrapper-win/)